# perl script without using DBI

Tags: database, perl, postgresql, populate

I have to make a perl script populate a database in PostgreSQL without using DBI or any sort of database interface model. I am a beginner to scripting so naturally, I'v been stuck on this for quite a while. I only have this much so far.

```
    open my $pipe, '|-', "psql -d postgres -U postgres", @options or die;
    # NOT SURE WHAT TO DO AFTER THIS

    close $pipe;
```

edit 1: Now i'm trying to do this.

```
 for ($count = $iters; $count >= 1; $count--) {
    $randdecimal = rand();
    $pipe "INSERT INTO random_table (runid, random_number) VALUES ($runid, $randdecimal)";
 }
```

but it gives me a syntax error

Comment: You may be better off generating a big sql file, and just shelling out to postgres to read it. Interacting statement-by-statement via `open` could get horribly complicated.

Comment: `print $pipe "SELECT * FROM TheTable;\n"`, but you'd be better off using DBI by a large margin.  What you are attempting is not sensible.

Comment: Could you elaborate one that please or maybe provide an example?

Comment: If you're asking me, the answer is no.  I like you too much to be willing to inflict the pain of processing SQL via pipes in Perl.

Comment: but all i need to do is insert into a table an arbitrary number of times. Nothing more than that

Comment: OK: on your head be it: `print $pipe "INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(1, 2, 3);"`.  Rinse and repeat.  Error detection is not going to be possible with things set up as they are; the error information is going to standard error and standard output.  And that's why you don't want to do it the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: So, erm... why are you attempting to do this the hardest, buggiest way possible? You _really_ should use DBI. It will be easier and more robust.

Comment: Why no DBI ? What re the constraints that prevent you from using DBI?

Answer (score 2):

Like the others say, DBI is *much* better than printing to a pipe.

However, there is a halfway house. Just print all your SQL to STDOUT and then do something like:

```
myscript.pl | psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --single-transaction -f -
```

This lets you easily check your script output / send it to a file. The psql options stop on the first error, wrap everything in a transaction and read from STDIN. You might want the usual -h/-U options too.

Personally, I tend to have two terminals open and just write to a .sql file then \i from a psql prompt. I like having a record of what command I ran.